# Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard function keys unreliable

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard connected to my 2011 MacBook Pro.

The keyboard's normal keys (letters, etc.) always work fine; however, there is a problem with the various function keys.

Basically, they don't work until I go to System Preferences -> Microsoft Keyboard. Once I go to that prefpane, everything starts working again.

It seems to somewhat randomly stop working, requiring me to go to System Preferences again to make it work.

How can I fix this? It seems like a daemon/driver that's supposed to make the keys work is crashing, but I searched Console.app for microsoft with no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that **Microsoft Keyboard Helper** is somehow not being added to the **Login Items** by the keyboard's driver installer. However, the helper is contained inside the **Microsoft Keyboard** Preference Pane, so it is being run when you open it, and thus restores the full functionality of the keyboard.

The simple solution is this:

1. Open **System Preferences**;
2. Go to **Users & Groups > {your user} > Login Items**;
3. Click **+** icon under the Login Items list;
4. When Finder window opens, press <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>;
5. When a form appears, paste this into it: 
   `/Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft Keyboard.prefPane/Contents/Resources/`;
6. Select the file **MicrosoftKeyboardHelper**, and press **Add**;

That's it. The keyboard should now retain its function keys' functionality after the restart.

Comment: This is a devilishly subtle issue because the first thing you do to try to fix it (opening the Preference Panel) does indeed fix it until you restart or log out.  I think I've probably wasted hours on this over the years, so many thanks for supplying the, obvious in hindsight, solution.

Answer (score 16):

I also have the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard. In my case the simple solution was to press the `F Lock` key at the far right of the function row (left of the `Print Screen` button). I didn't realize the button even existed until now.

Comment: I logged in just to upvoted this :|